# DB2 Federated Setup with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, db2, aix, federation

I have a strange issue, the application that I am working on is using DB2 9.7.6 on AIX and connects to a few views on a Oracle 11g r2 DB.

The views are quite complex but we are able to get a response quite fast. But some times the query gets stuck for no reason!

DB2 snapshot / DB2TOP shows that the query is waiting for response from remote.

We have seen the Oracle's AWR and SQL AWR for the related SQL and it seems there are multiple execution plans for the same query, I guess Oracle chooses to pick up the "bad" plan depending the the current data, but I see not much difference in the data compared to when the query was working perfectly.

While the query is stuck (being called from a java code) I can still execute the same query from SQL Developer or other DB2 clients! This is what confuses me most.

Do you guys have any suggestion on how what else I can do to investigate the root cause?

Cheers

Comment: If the query _get stuck_, as you say, in the Oracle database, you'll probably want to run the session trace there to see what's happening. At the same time I'd use the activity event monitor on the DB2 side to identify where the time is being spent -- could be the network.

Comment: These are valuable comments, I will get the Oracle DBA to get the required details. Many thanks for this :)